# Symmetric relationship in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship, relation

I've been using Translation API, but it's recommended to cache traslations, because of unnecessary server trips, so I cache it in a postgres database.

So I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE translation_cache(
    src_lang_code CHAR(3),
    dst_lang_code CHAR(3),
    src VARCHAR,
    dst VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(src_lang_code, dst_lang_code, src)
);
```

Which means, that for every string `src` there is only one translation from `src_lang_code` to `dst_lang_code`. But this is a symmetric relation! `dog (en) -> собака (ru); собака (ru) -> dog (en)`, and there is no other way!

Is there a beautiful way to implement such symmetric relations in postgres or should I go ugly and replicate data?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your data model seems to do what you intend.

Comment: imagine situation, where I translate a word from EN to RU (dog - собака). Now it's cached. After that I might wanna fetch the same translation, but the other way around: from RU to EN (собака - dog). But there is no such translation in cache, since only EN to RU was cached, so the program would make a request to the server to fetch a translation and then cache it, even though it's the same 1 to 1 relationship. Of course I could've cached both EN to RU and RU to EN, but they are identical, so it's data redundancy. Is there a way to make the relationship symmetrical without copying the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no very pretty solution to that.

You can either search the table twice whenever you need to look up a translation, or you can add a trigger that adds a second mirror-image row whenever a row is inserted.

In the first case, you should add a unique constraint that doesn't allow the same `dst` for the same pair of languages.

Let me add that this translation model is overly simplistic. A word rarely corresponds to a single word in another language, so the relationship is usually not symmetric.

Comment: you're correct about the overly simplistic model part, but my database translates names of cities, so I suppose my assumption about the symmetry should be correct. really discouraging, that there is no nice way to go about the symmetric relations. but I guess that's the nature of tables in the relational databases.